# Popup menu don't appear IOS

Tags: ios, menu

i want to make a pop up menu after click on UIImage. I have the controller with the UIImage, i have the action method, need only the implementation of the menu 
Menu options: Call, Text, Send e-mail.
How i do that?

```
-(IBAction)open:(id)sender {
    if(self.draw == 0) {
        self.draw = 1;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

    self.menu.frame =CGRectMake(0, 600, 320, 100);
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.menu];
    }
    else {
        self.draw = 0;

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [UIView setAnimationDelay:0.5];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

        self.menu.frame =CGRectMake(0, 400, 320, 100);
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.menu];
    }
}
```

This menu is not opening after click on button, only when i click on cell in tableview, and how i add options to the menu

Answer (score 0):

Impliment KGModel Library

KGModal is an easy drop in control that allows you to display any view in a modal popup. The modal will automatically scale to fit the content view and center it on screen with nice animations! ["click hear"](https://github.com/kgn/KGModal.git)